# (Html.DropdownList) Value cannot be null. Parameter name: items

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a Login View Page with 2 partial views `_LoginPartial` and `_RegisterPartial`. And in `_RegisterPartial` I  have dropdownlist that contains the roles.

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CompanyProfile, new SelectList(ViewBag.CompanyProfiles, "AccountId", "AccountName"), "Select", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

I'm initializing this dropdownlist in the GET Method as

```
 //
    // GET: /Account/Login
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.CompanyProfiles = util.GetCompanyProfiles();
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }
```

and my code for getting the list from database is

```
 public List<abo_AccountType> GetCompanyProfiles()
    {
        List<abo_AccountType> companyProfiles = new List<abo_AccountType>();
        companyProfiles = db.GetAccountTypes().ToList();
        return companyProfiles;
    }
```

The list is initialized when we open the Login Page and I know that I need to initialize the dropdownlist again in the POST  method, so I'm doing that just like I did it in the GET Method

```
    //
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        ViewBag.CompanyProfiles = util.GetCompanyProfiles();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewBag.CompanyProfiles = util.GetCompanyProfiles();
            string[] errors = util.CheckDuplicateAccount(model);
            if (errors == null)
            {
                long currentUser = Convert.ToInt64(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());
                util.CreateNewAccount(model, currentUser);
            }

            else
            {
                AddErrors(errors);
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }
```

Even though I'm initializing the dropdown again I still get the error that `Value cannot be null. Parameter name: items`.
I've searched almost all the answers on SO and they all say that I need to initialize the dropdown again, which I'm doing, so why am I still getting this error.

Comment: All you POST method does is redirect. It does not return the view so setting a `ViewBag` property is pointless - and doing it twice is even more pointless. The code you have shown will not generate that error - its code that you have not shown which is the problem.

Comment: @StephenMuecke okay but all the answers(on other questions) suggest that we we need to populate the dropdown again in the POST method(and that worked for me when my register and login modules were in different Views) so naturally that's what I did this time too but  it doesn't to work in this scenario.

Comment: Also people please do give reasons when you down vote a question.

Comment: Yes you need to repopulate it and then return the view. But your not returning the view - your redirecting to a different method so `ViewBag.CompanyProfiles = util.GetCompanyProfiles();` is pointless (its lost the moment you redirect). And the down-vote is because you have not shown the relevant code (best guess is that you have a dropdown in your `Login()` method and its that method that is throwing the exception - the code you have shown will NOT throw it)

Answer (score 0):

You should generate "GET" method for Register and set CompanyProfiles in there.

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Register()
{
    ViewBag.CompanyProfiles = util.GetCompanyProfiles();
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Doing that gives the error: `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'LoginViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'RegisterViewModel'.` Also I cannot have separate Views for Login and Register, I need to have both these modules on the same page

Answer (score 0):

Create another model that having both the properties of that two models and pass it in your post action.

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Register(combinedModel model)
{
    ViewBag.CompanyProfiles = util.GetCompanyProfiles();
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: I was actually trying to avoid that. Is there no other way to go about it?

Comment: since your actions corresponding to 2 model. you have to do with 2 models in my view. and you are using partial views too. thats y you should use view model concept

Comment: well I am using view models, but both login and register view models are separate because both have different business logic, but I guess if I can't find any another solution I'll have to combine both of those.

Comment: make sure your get method passing required model correctly.

Comment: it is, i checked